# Remove skipped test results from testng execution

Tags: automated-tests, testng

Hi i want to remove all the test results which were skipped in test execution from appearing in the HTML report which testng generates. Any idea how can i achieve that. I know that there is IReporter which could be used as listener to generate reports. but then i only want to modify the Reports generated by testng. I do not want to generate my own reports. Any idea how  i can achieve it. TIA!!!

```
import java.util.List;

import org.testng.IReporter;
import org.testng.ISuite;
import org.testng.xml.XmlSuite;

public class ReporterListener implements IReporter {

    @Override
    public void generateReport(List<XmlSuite> xmlSuites, List<ISuite> suites,
            String outputDirectory) 
    {
     //What code should come here....
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can achieve this only by customizing the TestNG report. I have done this for one of my requirements. Here is the code for the customReport. In the generateSuiteSummaryReport(suites), generateMethodSummaryReport(suites) you can stop the Skipped tests logic. Just have this class extend the ReporterListener.

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;

import org.testng.IInvokedMethod;
import org.testng.IResultMap;
import org.testng.ISuite;
import org.testng.ISuiteResult;
import org.testng.ITestClass;
import org.testng.ITestContext;
import org.testng.ITestNGMethod;
import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.Reporter;
import org.testng.collections.Lists;
import org.testng.internal.Utils;
import org.testng.log4testng.Logger;
import org.testng.xml.XmlSuite;

/**
 * Reporter that generates a single-page HTML report of the test results.
 * <p>
 * Based on an earlier implementation by Paul Mendelson.
 * </p>
 * 
 * @author Abraham Lin
 */
  public class CustomReport extends CustomReportListener {
private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(CustomReport.class);

// ~ Instance fields ------------------------------------------------------

private PrintWriter m_out;

private int m_row;

private Integer m_testIndex;

private int m_methodIndex;

private Scanner scanner;

// ~ Methods --------------------------------------------------------------

/** Creates summary of the run */
@Override
public void generateReport(List<XmlSuite> xml, List<ISuite> suites,
        String outdir) {
    try {
        m_out = createWriter(outdir);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOG.error("output file", e);
        return;
    }

    startHtml(m_out);
    generateSuiteSummaryReport(suites);
    generateMethodSummaryReport(suites);
    generateMethodDetailReport(suites);
    endHtml(m_out);
    m_out.flush();
    m_out.close();
}

protected PrintWriter createWriter(String outdir) throws IOException {
    new File(outdir).mkdirs();
    return new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File(
            outdir, "BANC Selenium RC Execution Report.html"))));
}

/**
 * Creates a table showing the highlights of each test method with links to
 * the method details
 */
protected void generateMethodSummaryReport(List<ISuite> suites) {
    m_methodIndex = 0;
    startResultSummaryTable("methodOverview");
    int testIndex = 1;
    for (ISuite suite : suites) {
        if (suites.size() > 1) {
            titleRow(suite.getName(), 5);
        }
        Map<String, ISuiteResult> r = suite.getResults();
        for (ISuiteResult r2 : r.values()) {
            ITestContext testContext = r2.getTestContext();
            String testName = testContext.getName();
            m_testIndex = testIndex;
            resultSummary(suite, testContext.getFailedConfigurations(),
                    testName, "failed", " (configuration methods)");
            resultSummary(suite, testContext.getFailedTests(), testName,
                    "failed", "");
            resultSummary(suite, testContext.getSkippedConfigurations(),
                    testName, "skipped", " (configuration methods)");
            resultSummary(suite, testContext.getSkippedTests(), testName,
                    "skipped", "");
            resultSummary(suite, testContext.getPassedTests(), testName,
                    "passed", "");
            testIndex++;
        }
    }
    m_out.println("</table>");
}

/** Creates a section showing known results for each method */
protected void generateMethodDetailReport(List<ISuite> suites) {
    m_methodIndex = 0;
    for (ISuite suite : suites) {
        Map<String, ISuiteResult> r = suite.getResults();
        for (ISuiteResult r2 : r.values()) {
            ITestContext testContext = r2.getTestContext();
            if (r.values().size() > 0) {
                m_out.println("<h1>" + testContext.getName() + "</h1>");
            }
            resultDetail(testContext.getFailedConfigurations());
            resultDetail(testContext.getFailedTests());
            resultDetail(testContext.getSkippedConfigurations());
            resultDetail(testContext.getSkippedTests());
            resultDetail(testContext.getPassedTests());
        }
    }
}

/**
 * @param tests
 */
private void resultSummary(ISuite suite, IResultMap tests, String testname,
        String style, String details) {
    if (tests.getAllResults().size() > 0) {
        StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();
        String lastClassName = "";
        int mq = 0;
        int cq = 0;
        for (ITestNGMethod method : getMethodSet(tests, suite)) {
            m_row += 1;
            m_methodIndex += 1;
            ITestClass testClass = method.getTestClass();
            String className = testClass.getName();
            if (mq == 0) {
                String id = (m_testIndex == null ? null : "t"
                        + Integer.toString(m_testIndex));
                titleRow(testname + " &#8212; " + style + details, 5, id);
                m_testIndex = null;
            }
            if (!className.equalsIgnoreCase(lastClassName)) {
                if (mq > 0) {
                    cq += 1;
                    m_out.print("<tr class=\"" + style
                            + (cq % 2 == 0 ? "even" : "odd") + "\">"
                            + "<td");
                    if (mq > 1) {
                        m_out.print(" rowspan=\"" + mq + "\"");
                    }
                    m_out.println(">" + lastClassName + "</td>" + buff);
                }
                mq = 0;
                buff.setLength(0);
                lastClassName = className;
            }
            Set<ITestResult> resultSet = tests.getResults(method);
            long end = Long.MIN_VALUE;
            long start = Long.MAX_VALUE;
            for (ITestResult testResult : tests.getResults(method)) {
                if (testResult.getEndMillis() > end) {
                    end = testResult.getEndMillis();
                }
                if (testResult.getStartMillis() < start) {
                    start = testResult.getStartMillis();
                }
            }
            mq += 1;
            if (mq > 1) {
                buff.append("<tr class=\"" + style
                        + (cq % 2 == 0 ? "odd" : "even") + "\">");
            }
            String description = method.getDescription();
            String testInstanceName = resultSet
                    .toArray(new ITestResult[] {})[0].getTestName();
            buff.append("<td><a href=\"#m"
                    + m_methodIndex
                    + "\">"
                    + qualifiedName(method)
                    + " "
                    + (description != null && description.length() > 0 ? "(\""
                            + description + "\")"
                            : "")
                    + "</a>"
                    + (null == testInstanceName ? "" : "<br>("
                            + testInstanceName + ")") + "</td>"
                    + "<td class=\"numi\">" + resultSet.size() + "</td>"
                    + "<td>" + start + "</td>" + "<td class=\"numi\">"
                    + (end - start) + "</td>" + "</tr>");
        }
        if (mq > 0) {
            cq += 1;
            m_out.print("<tr class=\"" + style
                    + (cq % 2 == 0 ? "even" : "odd") + "\">" + "<td");
            if (mq > 1) {
                m_out.print(" rowspan=\"" + mq + "\"");
            }
            m_out.println(">" + lastClassName + "</td>" + buff);
        }
    }
}

/** Starts and defines columns result summary table */
private void startResultSummaryTable(String style) {
    tableStart(style, "summary");
    m_out.println("<tr><th>Class</th>"
            + "<th>Method</th><th># of<br/>Scenarios</th><th>Start</th><th>Time<br/>(ms)</th></tr>");
    m_row = 0;
}

private String qualifiedName(ITestNGMethod method) {
    StringBuilder addon = new StringBuilder();
    String[] groups = method.getGroups();
    int length = groups.length;
    if (length > 0 && !"basic".equalsIgnoreCase(groups[0])) {
        addon.append("(");
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            if (i > 0) {
                addon.append(", ");
            }
            addon.append(groups[i]);
        }
        addon.append(")");
    }

    return "<b>" + method.getMethodName() + "</b> " + addon;
}

private void resultDetail(IResultMap tests) {
    for (ITestResult result : tests.getAllResults()) {
        ITestNGMethod method = result.getMethod();
        m_methodIndex++;
        String cname = method.getTestClass().getName();
        m_out.println("<h2 id=\"m" + m_methodIndex + "\">" + cname + ":"
                + method.getMethodName() + "</h2>");
        Set<ITestResult> resultSet = tests.getResults(method);
        generateForResult(result, method, resultSet.size());
        m_out.println("<p class=\"totop\"><a href=\"#summary\">back to summary</a></p>");

    }
}

/**
 * Write the first line of the stack trace
 * 
 * @param tests
 */
private void getShortException(IResultMap tests) {

    for (ITestResult result : tests.getAllResults()) {
        m_methodIndex++;
        Throwable exception = result.getThrowable();
        List<String> msgs = Reporter.getOutput(result);
        boolean hasReporterOutput = msgs.size() > 0;
        boolean hasThrowable = exception != null;
        if (hasThrowable) {
            boolean wantsMinimalOutput = result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SUCCESS;
            if (hasReporterOutput) {
                m_out.print("<h3>"
                        + (wantsMinimalOutput ? "Expected Exception"
                                : "Failure") + "</h3>");
            }

            // Getting first line of the stack trace
            String str = Utils.stackTrace(exception, true)[0];
            scanner = new Scanner(str);
            String firstLine = scanner.nextLine();
            m_out.println(firstLine);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Write all parameters
 * 
 * @param tests
 */
private void getParameters(IResultMap tests) {

    for (ITestResult result : tests.getAllResults()) {
        m_methodIndex++;
        Object[] parameters = result.getParameters();
        boolean hasParameters = parameters != null && parameters.length > 0;
        if (hasParameters) {

            for (Object p : parameters) {
                m_out.println(Utils.escapeHtml(org.testng.internal.Utils
                        .toString(p, String.class)) + " | ");
            }
        }

    }
}

private void generateForResult(ITestResult ans, ITestNGMethod method,
        int resultSetSize) {
    Object[] parameters = ans.getParameters();
    boolean hasParameters = parameters != null && parameters.length > 0;
    if (hasParameters) {
        tableStart("result", null);
        m_out.print("<tr class=\"param\">");
        for (int x = 1; x <= parameters.length; x++) {
            m_out.print("<th>Param." + x + "</th>");
        }
        m_out.println("</tr>");
        m_out.print("<tr class=\"param stripe\">");
        for (Object p : parameters) {
            m_out.println("<td>"
                    + Utils.escapeHtml(Utils.toString(p, String.class))
                    + "</td>");
        }
        m_out.println("</tr>");
    }
    List<String> msgs = Reporter.getOutput(ans);
    boolean hasReporterOutput = msgs.size() > 0;
    Throwable exception = ans.getThrowable();
    boolean hasThrowable = exception != null;
    if (hasReporterOutput || hasThrowable) {
        if (hasParameters) {
            m_out.print("<tr><td");
            if (parameters.length > 1) {
                m_out.print(" colspan=\"" + parameters.length + "\"");
            }
            m_out.println(">");
        } else {
            m_out.println("<div>");
        }
        if (hasReporterOutput) {
            if (hasThrowable) {
                m_out.println("<h3>Test Messages</h3>");
            }
            for (String line : msgs) {
                m_out.println(line + "<br/>");
            }
        }
        if (hasThrowable) {
            boolean wantsMinimalOutput = ans.getStatus() == ITestResult.SUCCESS;
            if (hasReporterOutput) {
                m_out.println("<h3>"
                        + (wantsMinimalOutput ? "Expected Exception"
                                : "Failure") + "</h3>");
            }
            generateExceptionReport(exception, method);
        }
        if (hasParameters) {
            m_out.println("</td></tr>");
        } else {
            m_out.println("</div>");
        }
    }
    if (hasParameters) {
        m_out.println("</table>");
    }
}

protected void generateExceptionReport(Throwable exception,
        ITestNGMethod method) {
    m_out.print("<div class=\"stacktrace\">");
    m_out.print(Utils.stackTrace(exception, true)[0]);
    m_out.println("</div>");
}

/**
 * Since the methods will be sorted chronologically, we want to return the
 * ITestNGMethod from the invoked methods.
 */
private Collection<ITestNGMethod> getMethodSet(IResultMap tests,
        ISuite suite) {
    List<IInvokedMethod> r = Lists.newArrayList();
    List<IInvokedMethod> invokedMethods = suite.getAllInvokedMethods();
    for (IInvokedMethod im : invokedMethods) {
        if (tests.getAllMethods().contains(im.getTestMethod())) {
            r.add(im);
        }
    }
    Arrays.sort(r.toArray(new IInvokedMethod[r.size()]), new TestSorter());
    List<ITestNGMethod> result = Lists.newArrayList();

    // Add all the invoked methods
    for (IInvokedMethod m : r) {
        result.add(m.getTestMethod());
    }

    // Add all the methods that weren't invoked (e.g. skipped) that we
    // haven't added yet
    for (ITestNGMethod m : tests.getAllMethods()) {
        if (!result.contains(m)) {
            result.add(m);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public void generateSuiteSummaryReport(List<ISuite> suites) {

    printExecutionParameters();

    m_out.println("<b align=\"center\">Execution Summary</b>");
    tableStart("testOverview", null);
    m_out.print("<tr>");
    tableColumnStart("Test");
    tableColumnStart("Methods<br/>Passed");
    tableColumnStart("Scenarios<br/>Passed");
    tableColumnStart("# skipped");
    tableColumnStart("# failed");
    tableColumnStart("Total<br/>Time");
    tableColumnStart("Included<br/>Groups");
    tableColumnStart("Excluded<br/>Groups");
    m_out.println("</tr>");
    NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.0");
    int qty_tests = 0;
    int qty_pass_m = 0;
    int qty_pass_s = 0;
    int qty_skip = 0;
    int qty_fail = 0;
    long time_start = Long.MAX_VALUE;
    long time_end = Long.MIN_VALUE;
    m_testIndex = 1;
    for (ISuite suite : suites) {
        if (suites.size() > 1) {
            titleRow(suite.getName(), 8);
        }
        Map<String, ISuiteResult> tests = suite.getResults();
        for (ISuiteResult r : tests.values()) {
            qty_tests += 1;
            ITestContext overview = r.getTestContext();
            startSummaryRow(overview.getName());
            int q = getMethodSet(overview.getPassedTests(), suite).size();
            qty_pass_m += q;
            summaryCell(q, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
            q = overview.getPassedTests().size();
            qty_pass_s += q;
            summaryCell(q, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
            q = getMethodSet(overview.getSkippedTests(), suite).size();
            qty_skip += q;
            summaryCell(q, 0);
            q = getMethodSet(overview.getFailedTests(), suite).size();
            qty_fail += q;
            summaryCell(q, 0);
            time_start = Math.min(overview.getStartDate().getTime(),
                    time_start);
            time_end = Math.max(overview.getEndDate().getTime(), time_end);
            summaryCell(
                    formatter.format((overview.getEndDate().getTime() - overview
                            .getStartDate().getTime()) / 1000.)
                            + " seconds", true);
            summaryCell(overview.getIncludedGroups());
            summaryCell(overview.getExcludedGroups());
            m_out.println("</tr>");
            m_testIndex++;
        }
    }
    if (qty_tests > 1) {
        m_out.println("<tr class=\"total\"><td>Total</td>");
        summaryCell(qty_pass_m, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        summaryCell(qty_pass_s, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        summaryCell(qty_skip, 0);
        summaryCell(qty_fail, 0);
        summaryCell(formatter.format((time_end - time_start) / 1000.)
                + " seconds", true);
        m_out.println("<td colspan=\"2\">&nbsp;</td></tr>");
    }
    m_out.println("</table>");
    m_out.println("<p></p>");
}

private void printExecutionParameters() {
    m_out.println("<b>Execution Parameters</b>");
    tableStart("testOverview", null);
    m_out.print("<tr>");
    tableColumnStart("AppicationURL");
    tableColumnStart("AppUserName|Password");
    tableColumnStart("DatabaseURL");
    tableColumnStart("DBUserName|Password");
    m_out.println("</tr>");
    summaryCell(applicationURL, true);
    summaryCell(applicationUserID + "|" + applicationPassword, true);
    summaryCell(databaseURL, true);
    summaryCell(databaseUserID + "|" + databasePassword, true);
    m_out.println("</table>");
    m_out.println("<p></p>");
}

private void summaryCell(String[] val) {
    StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer();
    for (String v : val) {
        b.append(v + " ");
    }
    summaryCell(b.toString(), true);
}

private void summaryCell(String v, boolean isgood) {
    m_out.print("<td class=\"numi" + (isgood ? "" : "_attn") + "\">" + v
            + "</td>");
}

private void startSummaryRow(String label) {
    m_row += 1;
    m_out.print("<tr"
            + (m_row % 2 == 0 ? " class=\"stripe\"" : "")
            + "><td style=\"text-align:left;padding-right:2em\"><a href=\"#t"
            + m_testIndex + "\">" + label + "</a>" + "</td>");
}

private void summaryCell(int v, int maxexpected) {
    summaryCell(String.valueOf(v), v <= maxexpected);
}

private void tableStart(String cssclass, String id) {
    m_out.println("<table cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\""
            + (cssclass != null ? " class=\"" + cssclass + "\""
                    : " style=\"padding-bottom:2em\"")
            + (id != null ? " id=\"" + id + "\"" : "") + ">");
    m_row = 0;
}

private void tableColumnStart(String label) {
    m_out.print("<th>" + label + "</th>");
}

private void titleRow(String label, int cq) {
    titleRow(label, cq, null);
}

private void titleRow(String label, int cq, String id) {
    m_out.print("<tr");
    if (id != null) {
        m_out.print(" id=\"" + id + "\"");
    }
    m_out.println("><th colspan=\"" + cq + "\">" + label + "</th></tr>");
    m_row = 0;
}

/** Starts HTML stream */
protected void startHtml(PrintWriter out) {
    out.println("<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd\">");
    out.println("<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">");
    out.println("<head>");
    out.println("<title>BANC Selenium RC Execution Report</title>");
    out.println("<style type=\"text/css\">");
    out.println("table {margin-bottom:10px;border-collapse:collapse;empty-cells:show}");
    out.println("td,th {border:1px solid #009;padding:.25em .5em}");
    out.println(".result th {vertical-align:bottom}");
    out.println(".param th {padding-left:1em;padding-right:1em}");
    out.println(".param td {padding-left:.5em;padding-right:2em}");
    out.println(".stripe td,.stripe th {background-color: #E6EBF9}");
    out.println(".numi,.numi_attn {text-align:right}");
    out.println(".total td {font-weight:bold}");
    out.println(".passedodd td {background-color: #0A0}");
    out.println(".passedeven td {background-color: #3F3}");
    out.println(".skippedodd td {background-color: #CCC}");
    out.println(".skippedodd td {background-color: #DDD}");
    out.println(".failedodd td,.numi_attn {background-color: #F33}");
    out.println(".failedeven td,.stripe .numi_attn {background-color: #D00}");
    out.println(".stacktrace {white-space:pre;font-family:monospace}");
    out.println(".totop {font-size:85%;text-align:center;border-bottom:2px solid #000}");
    out.println("</style>");
    out.println("</head>");
    out.println("<body>");
}

/** Finishes HTML stream */
protected void endHtml(PrintWriter out) {
    out.println("<center> Customized TestNG Report </center>");
    out.println("</body></html>");
}

// ~ Inner Classes --------------------------------------------------------
/** Arranges methods by classname and method name */
private class TestSorter implements Comparator<IInvokedMethod> {
    // ~ Methods
    // -------------------------------------------------------------

    /** Arranges methods by classname and method name */
    @Override
    public int compare(IInvokedMethod o1, IInvokedMethod o2) {
        // System.out.println("Comparing " + o1.getMethodName() + " " +
        // o1.getDate()
        // + " and " + o2.getMethodName() + " " + o2.getDate());
        return (int) (o1.getDate() - o2.getDate());
        // int r = ((T) o1).getTestClass().getName().compareTo(((T)
        // o2).getTestClass().getName());
        // if (r == 0) {
        // r = ((T) o1).getMethodName().compareTo(((T) o2).getMethodName());
        // }
        // return r;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks!! I will try this and let you know